# Sonata Admin Bundle choice validate error

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am try edit or add product by Sonata Admin Bundle but validator always reject a "condition" field because "The value you selected is not a valid choice."

Admin class

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
        $formMapper
        ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Nazwa'))
        ->add('condition', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => Product::getConditions(), 
                'label' => 'Stan',  
        ));
}
```

Entity

```
/**
 * @Assert\Choice(callback = "getConditions")
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
 */
protected $condition;

public static function getConditions()
{
    return array('new', 'used');
}
```

Comment: Edited: * @ORM\Column(name="product_condition", type="string", length=10)

Comment: Last edit don't solve main problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

//..

```
->add('condition', 'entity', array(
                'class' => YourAppBundle:YourEntityProduct
                'label' => 'Stan',
      ));
```

..//

Comment: I am sorry but this make list all product instead of just condition of it. I used 'choices_as_values' => true and it's work but intends of text like "new" or "used" I have got number 0 or 1 to select.

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine is expecting to get string but you pass integer to it as value of your selected field.
That's what you pass:

```
 return array(
    0 => 'new',
    1 => 'used'
);
```

That's what you need(for example):

```
 return array(
    '0' => 'new',
    '1' => 'used'
);
```

Error is triggered by length validation on field.

Comment: I am sorry again but this is not working too. Nothing has changed. I am tried to change 'condition' type to integer and after that your array. Maybe it's a bug of Sonata Admin in Symfony 2.7? Can anybody check this because I am Symfony newbie. For now I am using  `return array(
      'new' => 'new',
      'used' => 'used'
  );` and `'choices_as_values' => true` but this is not a good solution

Answer (score 1):

Sonata uses values as labels to display  and Keys as values (passed to model). To get what you want your array should be like array('new' => 'new', 'used' => 'used');